# How to evaluate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{itx^2}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I need the solution of this integral:

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{itx^2}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$$ with $t 
\in \mathbb R$.

I know that $e^{itx^2}=\cos(tx^2)+i\sin(tx^2)$.
Maybe the Fourier transform or the theory of complex numbers can be useful.

Comment: See [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph215/Gaussian.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1 \over \root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \expo{\ic tx^{2}}\expo{-x^{2}/2}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 2\root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{\color{red}{1/2} - 1}\,\,
\expo{-\pars{1/2 - \ic t}x}\,\,\,\dd x
\end{align}
I'll evaluate the integral by means of the
[Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem).
Note that
$$
\expo{-\pars{1/2 - \ic t}x} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\bracks{-\pars{1/2 - \ic t}x}^{\,k} \over k!} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\pars{{1 \over 2} - \ic t}^{\,k}}\,
{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1 \over \root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \expo{\ic tx^{2}}\expo{-x^{2}/2}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 2\root{2\pi}}\Gamma\pars{1 \over 2}
\pars{{1 \over 2} - \ic t}^{\,-1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{1 \over 2\pars{1 - 2\ic t}^{1/2}} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

For real numbers $a>0$ it's well-known that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}. \tag{}\label{*}$$
Observe that the right hand side of \eqref{*} is an analytic function in $\Re a >0$. So we are done by analytic continuation if we can prove:

> **Lemma**  The function$$I(a):=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} dx$$
> is analytic in $\Re a >0$.

The result wanted is then simply $$\fbox{$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{itx^2}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx=\frac1{\sqrt {2\pi}}I\left(\frac12 - it\right)=\sqrt{\frac1{4-8it}}.$}$$

*Proof of lemma.* Indeed, setting $I_N(a):=\int_0^Ne^{-ax^2} dx$, by Fubini's theorem and Cauchy's theorem, if $\Gamma$ is any closed curve in $\Re a >0$,
$$ \int_{\Gamma} I_N(a) da = \int_0^N\int_{\Gamma} e^{-ax^2} da dx = 0,$$
so $I_N$ is analytic. Now if $\Re a>c>0$,
$$ |I(a) - I_N(a)| \le \int_N^\infty \left|e^{-ax^2}\right| dx=\int_N^\infty e^{-(\Re a) x^2}dx \le \int_N^\infty e^{-c x^2}dx \to 0.$$
So $I$ is the uniform limit of analytic functions $I_N$ on $\Re a>c$, for each $c>0$. Thus, by [the Weierstrass theorem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904418/the-weierstrass-theorem-from-complex-analysis) $I(a)$ is an analytic function on $\Re a > 0$. $\square$

---

notes-

1. The result that gives the analytic continuation is the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem): it states that the zeros of a non-zero analytic function are isolated. Thus if the two sides of \eqref{*} agree for $a>0$, their difference is zero on $(0,\infty)$ which is not an isolated set, hence the difference is the zero function.
2. To verify that this answer matches robjohn's:
   $$\sqrt{\frac1{4-8it}} = \frac12\sqrt{\frac1{1-2it}}\sqrt{\frac{1+2it}{1+2it}}= \frac12\sqrt{\frac{1+2it}{1+4t^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+2it}}{2\sqrt{1+4t^2}},$$
   and $1+2it = \sqrt{1+4t^2}\exp{i\theta}$ where $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ with $\operatorname{sgn}\theta=\operatorname{sgn}t$, $\cos\theta = \frac1{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}$. Thus $\cos(\theta/2)= \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}2}$, $\sin(\theta/2)=(\operatorname{sgn}\theta) \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \theta}2}$, and therefore
   \begin{align} \sqrt{1+2it} &=\sqrt{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}2} + i(\operatorname{sgn}\theta) \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \theta}2} \right) 
   \\
   &=  \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+4t^2}+1}2} + i(\operatorname{sgn} t) \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+4t^2}-1}2},\end{align}
   which gives robjohn's answer.
3. Finally I wanted to immortalize the [link](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph215/Gaussian.pdf) of mattos's comment, which is a note titled 'A Gaussian integral with a purely imaginary argument' by Howard E. Haber for his Physics 215 class of Winter 2018. There, it sketches robjohn's argument (if I understand it correctly), and then proves that \eqref{*} holds even if $\Re a = 0$ (of course, $a\neq 0$ is still required). I've saved the file and I don't intend to lose it. If the link goes dead, ping me and I may have a chance of rehosting it.

Comment: Good answer, but I do not understand what's the meaning of $sgn(\theta)$?. It means the math sing of $\theta$ ?

Comment: @DarlynLC Its the same notation as in robjohn's answer. $\operatorname{sgn}\theta$ is the sign of $\theta$, i.e. $$\operatorname{sgn}\theta := \begin{cases} 1 & \theta > 0 \\ 0 & \theta = 0 \\ -1 & \theta < 0. \end{cases}$$
Some people deal with the $\theta=0$ case differently but that's not important in our situation.

Comment: Thank you ! It's a new notation for me . Now I understand this!

Comment: @DarlynLC you're welcome :) glad you like the answer

Comment: @DarlynLC is there any other part of my answer you don't understand? Also I see that I'm the only person who voted +1 on robjohn's answer so far, if you like it enough to Accept it, consider voting for it as well (and my answer ;) )

Comment: There are no more parts that I don't understand. I already voted for robjohn's answer. Do not worry, I liked all the answers and I have to read them step by step.

Comment: @DarlynLC OK. I’m off to bed then, have a good day :)

Answer (score 2):

If $t \in \Re$, then

$$I=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{itx^2}e^{-x^2/2} dx=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1/2-it)x^2/2} dx.$$
Use $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}, \Re(a) >0$,
$$I=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-2it}}$$

Comment: Is it okay that we use that for complex a?

Comment: Yes, very much this is an integral on the real line, where $t$ is real. The thing is $\Re (a) >0$.

Comment: How to learn things like this? Complex analysis is related, but I feel it's more theoretical. Such techniques are perhaps more emphasized in courses of math method/complex method?

Comment: @CharlieChang I proved the result in my answer, using complex analysis (which I would say is indeed "theoretical")

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{itx^2}e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1\alpha\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^R e^{-x^2\alpha^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha x\tag1\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1\alpha\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^{\alpha R} e^{-z^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag2\\
&=\frac1{2\alpha}+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1\alpha\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_R}e^{-z^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag3\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4t^2}}2}+i\mathrm{sgn}(t)\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4t^2}}2}}{2\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: change the improper integral to a limit and
$\phantom{\text{(1):}}$ multiply and divide by $\alpha$ where
$\phantom{\text{(1):}}$ $\alpha^2=1-2it$ and $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)\gt0$
$\phantom{\text{(1):}}$ that is, $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4t^2}}2}-i\mathrm{sgn}(t)\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4t^2}}2}$
$\phantom{\text{(1):}}$ and $\dfrac1\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4t^2}}2}+i\mathrm{sgn}(t)\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4t^2}}2}}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}$
$(2)$: change to a contour integral where $z=\alpha x$
$(3)$: close the contour where
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ $\gamma_R=[0,\alpha R]\cup[\alpha R,R]\cup[R,0]$
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ the limit of the integral over $[\alpha R,R]$ vanishes
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ the limit of the integral over $[R,0]$ is
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ $-\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}2$
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ which is countered by adding $\frac1{2\alpha}$
$(4)$: there are no singularities inside the contour, so the integral is $0$